# SF Horror film of the 90s ending as the crew escapes in a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

It's a space exploration film, with some kind of alien creatures attacking a team of space explorers.
All I remember is that at the end of the film, the survivors manage to escape in their ship, and the last frame is of a bunch of spherical creatures (eggs?) that are moving about in the ship's hold.

They haunted my childhood, made me afraid of the dark.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: [Moontrap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=270j3YK2YMU)?

Comment: [Inseminoid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKjfjHHpOCg)?

Comment: [Critters 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critters_4) ?